# Fading from one image source to another in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm building a weather/travel info single-page site as a portfolio/practice project in React. There's a big 'jumbotron'-style element at the top of the page with the searchbar in the middle of it. By default it displays a generic photo of a beach, then once a city is searched for it changes to a photo of that city, pulled from a custom Google image search API.

This all works fine, but I'd love for one image to be able to fade to the other instead of abruptly changing! I've looked through the react-bootstrap and react-transitions-group documentation but not finding anything that will obviously do this.

Currently in the top-level App component I'm using a state 'imgUrl' which updates to the URL of the new image to show once the API returns it. Then the backgroundImage property of the JSX element is just this.state.imgUrl.

App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Searchbar from './components/Searchbar'
import Weather from './components/Weather'
import background from './default-bg.jpg'
import Attractions from './components/Attractions'
import ImageSearch from './components/ImageSearch'
import './App.css'

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    city: '',
    searched: false,
    lat: '',
    lon: '',
    imgPath: background,
    mainHeight: '596px'

  }

  city = (text) => {
    this.setState({ city: text, mainHeight: '400px' })
  }

  searched = (isSearched) => {
    this.setState({ searched: isSearched })
    
  }

  imgPath = (imgUrl) => {
    this.setState({ imgPath: imgUrl })
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="jumbotron justify-content-center align-items-center" style={{textAlign: "center", height: this.state.mainHeight, backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.imgPath})`, backgroundSize: "100%", backgroundPosition: "bottom", margin: "0"}}>
        <div className="container" style={{ width: "35%", backgroundColor: "seashell", opacity: "0.75", padding: "0 40px 10px 40px", borderRadius: "20px" }}>
        <span style={{ fontSize: "6em", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Snapshot</span>
        <h4 style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>The world at a glance</h4>
        </div>
        <br></br>

        <Searchbar city={this.city} searched={this.searched} />
      </div>

      {this.state.searched === true && 
      <div>
      <Weather city={this.state.city} />
      <Attractions city={this.state.city} />
      <ImageSearch city={this.state.city} imgPath={this.imgPath} />
      </div>
      }

    </div>
  );
}}

export default App
```

Image search component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ImageSearch extends Component {

    state = {
        city: this.props.city,
        cx: ###
        apiKey: ###
        imgUrl: ''
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
    const imgSearchUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${this.state.city}&num=1&searchType=image&key=${this.state.apiKey}&cx=${this.state.cx}`

        try {
            const imgRes = await fetch(imgSearchUrl)
                if (imgRes.ok) {
                    const imgJson = await imgRes.json()
                    console.log(imgJson)
                    this.setState({ imgUrl: imgJson.items[0].link })
                    this.props.imgPath(this.state.imgUrl)
                    
                    
                }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }
    

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share code examples of what you currently have, for more information please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Changing the `src` will always be abrupt, React or vanilla. To fade between images, you will generally want to use two images, opacity and CSS/JS animations.

Comment: @James Bradenburg - please see the comment below which provides several specific CSS attributes to apply to the image. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Cool idea! Also, it's neat that you're combining CSS within your component. There are several well-known advantages to that approach (I wrote about some of the pros and cons a while back here: https://x-team.com/blog/compare-cxs-jss-performance/).

There are at least a couple ways to create that kind of transition effect here (both for fading-out and fading-in):

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition - you can use the native CSS transition functionality. It gives you fine-grained control by specifying which CSS attributes you apply it too along with a duration for the effect. One disadvantage of that approach is that it will trigger every time the page is reloaded (depending on implementation specifics). To use this you'd need to add another CSS style attribute into your existing inline styles.
2. Another approach is to use keyframes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes - this can be handled entirely within CSS (without any fancy JS. It also won't give you some of the cool effects that fancy WebGL-enhanced JS will!). This allows you to define specific stages for an animation effect and the use-case you're describing is quite paradigm for it!

Cheers!

--

**Edit:** In order to be "more specific" (per a comment below), I'll also add a third approach.

This is a helpful, useful, specific, code-supplied technique discussed by this site: https://novelist.xyz/tech/progressive-background-image-loading/. I've slightly tweaked that example and added a few personal stylistic choices (but feel free to modify the general method to your tastes).

This approach applies less to a transition effect and more to the slight pause or delay that may occur when your users first load the new image for the first time in their browser. However, you will likely need to combine multiple approaches to optimize your implementation. Furthermore, the code snippet below can be used to handle more-general transition effects too.

JavaScript:

```js
const loadImg = (el) => {
  const url = el.getAttribute("data-src");

  let img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  img.onload = () => {
    el.classList.add("loaded");
    el.classList.remove("loading");
    el.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
  };
};
```

Your HTML:

```html
<div class="image loading" id="a" data-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537767017444-30935148a2f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3034&q=80">
```

Your CSS:

```
.image {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.loading {
  /* for a nicer aesthetically blurry effect use the following */
  /* background-image: filter(url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff), blur(1px)); */
  
  /* for performance make sure to use a small image placeholder file */
  /* That file will be loaded first (across all images where it's used) and cached */
  /* Alternatively, use "background: black;" so no image is loaded */
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
  filter: none;
  transition: -webkit-filter 0s 0.2s linear, filter 0s 0.2s linear;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.loaded {
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This approach can be combined with React or incorporated into the existing code.

Comment: No, it is an answer (I specifically stated that they can add that style attribute to their existing inline styles). Not to "brow-beat" the author but something like: `style={{ transition: 1s background }`. The author didn't specify the exact fade-in effect they were seeking. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Adam, I did try using the CSS transition method but it didn't work (I suppose because it's asking to 'fade' from one URL to another, rather than one image to another. I suspect it may not be possible, for the reasons that DBS stated. I did think about using two separate images and using a transition to adjust their opacities, but this would get complicated using repeated searches in the app...

Comment: Depending on the timing of the transition effect, how you setup your image classes, CSS, etc. the asynchronous loading of the image may prevent your transition effect from correctly rendering. (I ran into that myself early on when learning about this - that's why I provided general approaches rather than specifics - forgive any lack of specifics above.) I added a third approach above which uses a default background image (cached in the user's browser) or color to handle the slight delay in loading a new image for the first time.

Comment: To cause the existing image to fade out - you'll like want to trigger some kind of CSS transition effect (using opacity, blur, etc. as described above) after the search call is made (button is clicked). You're already using a default background color so you can fade to that and then fade into the next image as it loads.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think about the async/await function affecting it. But since the new URL isn't actually passed up to the App component until after the await expression is fulfilled it shouldn't affect it, or have I got that wrong? I think the approach I'm going to go for is to have two background image components, each one with a Boolean state to create a simple 1-bit memory, and flip which one displays as the user performs more searches. So would you say calling the CSS transition effect when the async/await is fulfilled would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: You're off to the right start thinking in those terms. From what I understand, you are async/awaiting a third-party endpoint to retrieve the image URL. While you are correct that the URL itself will be immediately available. The act of setting that on an image source (or in the CSS background-url) can still cause a delay as the image gets loaded. The last snippet I provided could have been clearer in explaining that. It handles the difference between getting the URL itself and the actual rendering and caching of the image the URL is pointing at.

Comment: A transition effect (can be opacity from 0 to 1, from background color to image, etc.) applies right after a transition event is triggered (changing image, changing CSS class/React Classname, rerendering, etc.) - just revisited the specification since I forgot LOL: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property.

Comment: A couple ways (piggy-backing off your outline there) include: (1) you might create a default CSS/React class/className that has a default background color like black and give it a transition effect like `transition: 2s opacity` and `opacity: 0` or something like that. When the user searches, you can give the element with that background that class then remove it on image load. Another way is to use some other preset image and include it within your static assets but the same approach applies generally there too. So, even when you get the URL, there's still a delay when loading the image.